# CakePHP 2.4 Auth Login return false

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.4

I have a problem with *Auth Component*, i give correct datas to my form but `Auth->Login()` continue to return false. I tried to get the SQL query but it didn't exist.

This is my code :

```
if ($this->request->data) {
   if(isset($this->data['User'])) {
      if($this->User->save($this->request->data)){
         $this->Session->setFlash(
                               'Félicitation, votre compte vient d\'être créer');
      }
   }elseif(isset($this->data['UserLogin'])) {
      if($this->Auth->login()){
         return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
      }else{
         $log = $this->User->getDataSource()->getLog(false, false); debug($log);
         $this->Session->setFlash(
                              'L\'identifiant ou le mot de passe est incorrect');
      }
   }
}

$this->set('universities', $this->User->University->find('list'));
```

I don't know at all what is this problem's source.

Comment: Why is there both saving and login in the same action? You want to directly log people in who just registered? Also, when adding a user, you should add create() before using save().

Comment: Thank for advice. In fact, i have login and register form on the same page. But when i try to log a user with the log form it didn't work.

Comment: Because you should not do that. At least not without mapping aliased fields back to "User". As the login auth code will look for that key and also the username and password fields under this one (not UserLogin). Even thought that might work it is highly untransparent. I recommend separating the logic here in a more appropriate way. You should also stick to CakePHP coding conventions (always braces around if/else etc). Mistakes will be easier to spot for yourself and everyone else.

Comment: Ok, so i separate my actions in two methods : "Add" and "Login", it still doesn't work. And for register form i don't receive validation's errors message. Cause i redirect to index from "add" method.

Comment: Login works fine now. But always this problem with errors message.